# How to create a messaging service across application in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to show messages to the end user, just like Google, at the top center of the web panel.

I don't want to include the HTML and related script everywhere in every form and list and chart that I have. I want to centralize this messaging functionality into a service (in Angular JS term) that can be used everywhere.

And just like Google, I want to be able to show rich text in my messages, that is, I want to include links and probably other HTML stuff there. For example instead of showing `Customer is defined`, I want to show `Customer is defined, <a href='#/customer/addPhone'>Now add a phone</a>` to guide the user.

What I've done is to place the messages HTML in the root layout of my single paged application:

```
<div class="appMessages">
    <span ng-show="message" ng-click="clearMessage()" ng-bind-html="message"></span>
</div>
```

and in our controllers, we inject the `$rootScope` and try to set the `message` property on it.

Yet I get no results. Can you guide me please?

Comment: May be try `$root.message` instead of `message`? Have you get any errors in the console telling the message is not trusted by $sce?

Comment: Could you add some JS code to see how you use the $rootScope ?

Answer (score 0):

As a general best practice I would avoid using $rootScope to pass the messages but rather use a dedicated service to update the message,
On your case the problem might be that you need to use angular `$sce` service to mark your html as trusted.
or load `ng-santize`module instead (which is a seperate module you need to load [see offical doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize))

That is needed because angular security requires you to explicitly check the html, if the source of your messages are from your code only, and not users inupts you can use the `trustAsHtml` as you know for sure it a safe html.

On your controller inject $sce, and bind it to your scope, and then use the $sce.trustAsHtml(value) function.

```
<div class="appMessages">
    <span ng-show="message" ng-click="clearMessage()" ng-bind-html="$sce.trustAsHtml(message)"></span>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .component('message', {
    controller: function($sce, messagService){
    this.messagService = messagService;
    this.$sce = $sce;  
    },
    template: '{{$ctrl.message}}<div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.$sce.trustAsHtml($ctrl.messagService.message)"></div>'
})
.service('messagService', function(){
  this.message = '';
  this.updateMessage = function(message){
   this.message = message;
  }
})
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, messagService){
    $scope.updateMessage = function () {
     messagService.updateMessage('wow <b style="color:yellow;">shiny</b> message');
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-app="app">
<message></message>
<button type="button" ng-click="updateMessage()"> update message</button>
</div>
```